# How to retrieve specific values from multidimensional associative arrays in php?

Tags: php, json, associative-array

I'm trying to loop through the following array so that I can print out the team name as well as the value in #text. So far I've decoded the json file and was able to format it in the following way in my php file, but I don't know how to get the specific data like the team name and #text. Any ideas on how to go about this? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

```
Array
(
  [overallteamstandings] => Array
    (
        [lastUpdatedOn] => 2019-12-11 4:40:09 PM
        [teamstandingsentry] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [team] => Array
                            (
                                [ID] => 56
                                [City] => Baltimore
                                [Name] => Ravens
                                [Abbreviation] => BAL
                            )

                        [rank] => 1
                        [stats] => Array
                            (
                                [GamesPlayed] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@abbreviation] => G
                                        [#text] => 13
                                    )

                                [PassAttempts] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@category] => Passing
                                        [@abbreviation] => Att
                                        [#text] => 360
                                    )

                                [PassCompletions] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@category] => Passing
                                        [@abbreviation] => Comp
                                        [#text] => 240
                                    )

                                [PassPct] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@category] => Passing
                                        [@abbreviation] => Pct
                                        [#text] => 66.7
                                    )

                                [PassGrossYards] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@category] => Passing
                                        [@abbreviation] => Yds
                                        [#text] => 2804
                                    )

                                [PassNetYards] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@category] => Passing
                                        [@abbreviation] => NetYds
                                        [#text] => 2687
                                    )

                                [PassAvg] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@category] => Passing
                                        [@abbreviation] => Avg
                                        [#text] => 7.8
                                    )

                                [PassYardsPerAtt] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@category] => Passing
                                        [@abbreviation] => Yards/Att
                                        [#text] => 7.0
                                    )

                                [PassTD] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@category] => Passing
                                        [@abbreviation] => TD
                                        [#text] => 29
                                    )

                                [PassTDPct] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@category] => Passing
                                        [@abbreviation] => TD%
                                        [#text] => 8.1
                                    )

                                [PassInt] => Array
                                    (
                                        [@category] => Passing
                                        [@abbreviation] => Int
                                        [#text] => 7
                                    )
```

Comment: Use foreach loop and get the correct value based on key.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data using [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop. But please try to use text as a string, currently it acts like a comment. Then Try this one

```
foreach($overallteamstandings as $overall) {
    foreach($overall['teamstandingsentry'] as $key=>$teams) {
        foreach($teams[$key] as $data) {
            foreach($data['stats'] as $keys=>$stat) {
                echo $stat['GamesPlayed']['#text'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```